# MVVM For Wp7 Enterprise App

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

I want to restructure my newly built Wp7 enterprise application using SqlLite Local Db and Consuming Java based SOAP web services.Currently it does not follow any design pattern.
I've been asked to re-structure the app using MVVM pattern.

I'm new to MVVM pattern .
Can anyone suggest good tutorial for MVVM targetting WP7 ?

Comment: MVVM-Light is a framework to get you started - extremely handy.

Answer (score 0):

As per the details at http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/ it's probably a good idea to start with the [Mix Video and slides (session EX14)](http://live.visitmix.com/Archive#VideoList) or any of the other articles linked at the end of the introduction.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) it's got some great support for Windows Phone 7 specific features including Tombstoning, Navigation and Tasks.

Comment: Does MVVM Light support all the WP7 specific features ?

Comment: I'm unsure, I haven't used it. But it's pretty much the other main MVVM framework on WP7. I'd recommend looking at examples of using both and seeing which "clicks" with you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Read my article [a framework for building of WP7 application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/PhoneCoreFramework.aspx) - it describes the framework for building of an application using MVVM pattern